# Adding Custom Type Definitions for Existing Libraries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web, frontend

Hi I am trying to add custom type definitions for `react-star-ratings`, i followed the [typescript documentation](https://www.credera.com/insights/typescript-adding-custom-type-definitions-for-existing-libraries) and for the time being I wanted to have a quick and dirty solution just to get the feature working, however it is not working and still give me error

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-star-ratings'. 'my_dir/.yarn/cache/react-star-ratings-npm-2.3.0-24c4488f30-0180c8389a.zip/node_modules/react-star-ratings/build/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-star-ratings` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-star-ratings';`  TS7016
```

This is my code
[image]